# Translate encoding of string

Tags: clojure, character-encoding, decode, windows-1252

I have a string that is in Windows-1252 encoding, but needs to be converted to UTF-8.

This is for a program that fixes a UTF-8 file that has fields containing Russian text encoded in [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) Windows-1252. Here's the code that decodes the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable):

```
(defn reencode
    [line]
    (str/replace line #"=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})"
        (fn [match] (apply str
            (map #(char (Integer/parseInt % 16)) (drop 1 match))))))
```

#### Here's the final code:

```
(defn reencode
    [line]
    (str/replace line #"(=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))+"
        (fn [[match ignore]]
            (String.
                (byte-array (map
                    #(Integer/parseInt (apply str (drop 1 %)) 16)
                    (partition 3 match)))
                "Windows-1252"))))
```

It fixes the encoding using `(String. ... "Encoding")` on all consecutive runs of quoted-printable-encoded characters. The original function was trying to decode pairs, so it would skip things like `=3D`, which is the quoted-printable entity for `=`.

Comment: Can you clarify the contents of the file? You say it's a UTF-8 file, but it also has Windows-1252 fields inside it. Is that correct?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, but the Windows-1252 fields have been represented in UTF-8 using [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). So I have a file as so: `2014-07-15 13:36:26 SMS` `\n`
`=D0=AF =D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B0=D1=8E`, which when converted using the above code, is: `2014-07-15 13:36:26 SMS` `\n` `Ð¯ Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð°Ñ`, rather than the expected `2014-07-15 13:36:26 SMS` `\n` `Я делаю`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to convert a Windows-1252 string from disk is to use the underlying Java primitives.

```
(def my-string (String. bytes-from-file "Windows-1252"))
```

will return you a Java String which has decoded the bytes with the Windows-1252 [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). From there you can spit bytes back out with UTF-8 encoding with

```
(.getBytes my-string "UTF-8")
```

Addressing your question more closely, if you have a file with mixed encodings then you could work out what delimits each encoding and read each set of bytes in separately using the method above.

Edit: The Windows-1252 string has been encoded with quoted printable. You will first need to decode it, using either your function or perhaps more preferably with [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html) using QuotedPrintable [decode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html%23decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), passing the Windows-1252 Charset. That will return a Java string which you can operate on directly with no further transformation.

N.B. for some measure of type safety, you should probably use Java [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) objects rather than Strings when specifying the charset to use (the String class can take either).

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do I use `(String.)`? The only way I can get it to work is `(String. "test")`. Attempts to use chars or lists of chars, or to specify an encoding, results in an `IllegalArgumentException` `No matching ctor found for class java.lang.String  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)`

Comment: You'll need to use one of the constructors in [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html](String). It takes either byte arrays or char arrays. We're you using a char array or a Clojure list of chars?

Comment: Ahh, okay. Didn't realize there was a `char[]` type distinct from `[\a \b \c]`. So `string`s and `char[]`s both work as the first argument to `(String.)`, but when I add a second argument, either `UTF-8` or `Windows-1252`, I still receive the same `IllegalArgumentException` posted above.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it to work with `(String. (byte-array '(list of integers)) "Encoding")`. Thanks for the help!